# How to create a full CSS box-shadow, not clipped

Tags: css

Experimenting with the CSS3 box-shadow property, I was wondering if you could prevent the object casting it to clip the shadow. In the following code the DIV casting the shadow is invisible, but the shadow is clipped nonetheless. Is there a way to get this done in CSS? Also maybe in JavaScript / JQuery? Or is the only way to set the box-shadow offset larger than the DIV, and reposition the shadow (not very elegant).

```
div#shadow
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    top: 100px;     
    left: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 100px 100px 100px gray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a fan of position elements off the page, but that might be a good way of doing it?

```
div#shadow {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    top: 100px;     
    left: -9999px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 10199px 100px 100px gray;
}
```

Give the `left` property a large negative value, then give the `box-shadow`'s left property a figure calculated using this formula:

```
0 - actual negative left + desired left + original box-shadow's left
```

So for your example above, it would be:

```
0 - -9999 + 100 + 100 = 10199
```

You can see it working in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/GcKpP/).

The only other way I could see would be to match the `border-radius` and `background-colour` of the `div` so that it matched the shadow. The `border-radius` would be `100px` in this case, but I couldn't match the `background-color` at all and off course it would change with different colours or images.

Comment: Thanks. You pretty much confirmed my question that the offset trick is the only one. I liked your ambition to fill the shadow, but I couldn't get that to work either. CSS wise that's the case closed. Maybe someone knows a JavaScript trick. But that probably would involve SVG or canvas. If no further reactions, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `opacity` instead of the transparant background-color it should work.

Comment: I'm afraid opacity will also hide the box-shadow.

Comment: Oh I thought that was what you meant. You solely want the shadow then, without the white lining of the div?